# Is there a keyboard featuring Undo/Redo?

Tags: keyboard, input-methods, text-input

Undo/redo feature is generally provided by input box host app, but.. the way Android's input works, it can be provided universally for all input boxes. Is there a keyboard which has undo/redo feature?

Comment: Comments explaining the downvotes would be nice...

Comment: I expect because you're basically asking for app recommendations, which don't do well on this site (or any site in Stack Exchange, actually). You're not asking help with a problem, you've already chosen your solution. Now you're using us to do your app searches for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default keyboard does not have the redo/undo features. However you can try some third-party keyboard app like [AI type keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android) which have these features.